# Why can't I get netcat talking to my Rails server?

Tags: webserver, netcat

I have a Thin server running locally, serving a Rails app. Following an example in the netcat man page, I'm trying to use `nc` to talk to my server:

```
echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" | nc 0.0.0.0 3000
```

But I get a 400 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close
Server: thin 1.6.1 codename Death Proof
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 requires providing a `Host:` header. You also need to add the `-e` flag to the `echo` command to escape character sequences, so

```
echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n" | nc 0.0.0.0 3000
```

would work, or alternatively you could use HTTP 1.0 which does not require the `Host:` header, so

```
echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc 0.0.0.0 3000
```

Comment: You're right on both counts. Thanks! Weird that the man page for `echo` makes no mention of the `-e` flag, at least on my system.

Comment: that's because you're using the shell builtin command, but the man page is for the `/bin/echo` command